# Linux: Process ignores signals

Tags: centos, bash, signals

Processes running in Linux ignores signals (INT,QUIT,TERM) except KILL. Programs such as top, tail -f, sleep and etc, do not respond when pressing Ctrl+C and thus have to stop them from another console using the kill utility.
Strace not showing any activity, and I see that the process doesn't got signals.

What could be the problem?

CentOS 6.5, kernel 3.10.23 (custom kernel build from OVH Hosting).

Comment: What is the status of the process ?

Comment: If you see the process doesn't receive signals, then the problem is not that the process is ignoring the signals. Does the process respond to kill -2 (SIGINT) ?  Is the process still attached to the tty? Show output of `ps -fp $PROCESSID`

Comment: Process in running state and not detached, it's a top utility for example.

`$ ps -fp 25923
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
pg       25923 23316  2 06:22 pts/0    00:00:00 top`

If I send SIGINT (or SIGTERM), process stay working as usual. Process exits only with SIGKILL.

Comment: the problem is not Linux or the OS. the problem is likely the terminal settings for your XTERM, PUTTY, or whatever you use to connect